How to search an array of strings for a value in Snowflake?
I have a string column in my table in the format "1 2 9" (example). I need to create a column checking if any of the values is 1.
I created an array from that string in a separate column by using "STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(TABLE.COLUMN1), ' '::TEXT), which is working. I now have Column2 which displays ["1","2","9"] for the above.
However, I cannot get ARRAY_CONTAINS to work properly. My current code is:
CASE 
     WHEN ARRAY_CONTAINS(STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(TABLE.COLUMN1,' '::TEXT),ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('1'::TEXT)) THEN TRUE 
     ELSE FALSE 
     END AS m_1

However this results in all rows returning False even when there's a 1 in the array. Any ideas? Thanks.

Hi - I’d start by reading the documentation for the array_contains function: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_contains

Try this, that might work for you.
ARRAY_CONTAINS('1'::TEXT, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('1', '2','9'));

You need to do it in the opposite order:
with data as(
    select '1 1 2 3 1 2 3' column1
    union all select '2 1 2 3 1 2 3 1'
    union all select '3 3'
)

select STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(COLUMN1,' '::TEXT)
    , CASE
     WHEN ARRAY_CONTAINS(STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(COLUMN1,' '::TEXT),ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('1'::TEXT)) THEN TRUE 
     ELSE FALSE 
     END AS your_original
    , CASE
     WHEN ARRAY_CONTAINS('1'::variant, STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(COLUMN1,' '::TEXT)) THEN TRUE 
     ELSE FALSE 
     END AS fixed
    , ARRAY_CONTAINS('1'::variant, STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(COLUMN1, ' ')) cleaner
from data



If space character is a reliable delimiter, wouldn't something as simple as this do the trick?
col ilike any ('1 %', '% 1 %', '% 1', '1') as new_col

